# Js not working in some collection pages shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify

I have a website https://monthlysommelier.com in shopify. In this if we navigate to any of the collection pages other than the "Wine Gifts", the search box is not displaying and for the wine gifts its okay. There is a js which is adding class to the search box div element and in wine gifts collection only, the js working and adding the class.
I have tried to debug by adding console log in the js file on different places, but the js is not working there. When i checked the page view source, the js is actually there in dom. But when i checked in network tab of browser, the js are not there.

Comment: Hello, Please take a look at this guideline for creating a good question on stackoverflow.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example